# How can I speed up the export of graphs in DIMACS format?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, export

I'm creating random graphs with suitable properties and exporting them in the [DIMACS format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/DIMACS.html). Already, for rather small graphs with, say, ~60k vertices and ~240k edges, `Export` takes several minutes on a high-end machine. My hope is to export much larger graphs in a reasonable time. Here's how I'm doing it now,

```
g = RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[Table[8, {60000}]]];
Export["graph.col", g]
```

The output file is a plaintext file with roughly $e$ lines, where $e$ is the number of edges in the graph. Why does `Export` run so slow? Is there a way I can speed `Export` up, or is there another way to do this faster? I can't imagine what makes *Mathematica* *so* slow at extracting the edgelist of the graph and writing it to a file.

Comment: @Öskå I don't think that's quite true (see my answer for a starter).

Comment: ... except if you rewrite the format manually.. :) But by using `Export` it's not possible :)

Comment: @Öskå Right, but what's the difference really between "exporting" and "writing the format manually"? Isn't this what `Export` should be doing in the first place? What on earth does it do to spend so much time? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract adjacency matrix and export it.

```
g = RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[Table[8, {10000}]]];

Export["g.col", AdjacencyMatrix[g]]
```

It will ignore vertex names, but it's not supported in DIMAC any way.

Comment: @mrm yes, when I tested, it's faster.

Comment: @halmir OK ... removed comments.  Though I wouldn't mind talking about it in chat ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why `Export` is slow.

The graph

```
g = RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[Table[8, {10000}]]];
```

has 10k vertices, and 40k edges. On my machine,

```
Timing[Export["g.col", g]]
```

requires 10.822373 seconds. I wrote a very quick & naive function for writing the same graph to a file:

```
WriteGraph[g_, filename_] :=
 Module[{},
  L = EdgeList[g];
  file = OpenWrite[filename];
  WriteString[file, 
   "p edge " <> ToString[VertexCount[g]] <> " " <> 
    ToString[EdgeCount[g]] <> "\n"];

  For[i = 1, i <= EdgeCount[g], ++i,
   first = L[[i]][[1]];
   second = L[[i]][[2]];
   str = "e "  <> ToString[first] <> " " <> ToString[second];
   WriteString[file, str];
   WriteString[file, "\n"];
   ];

  Close[file];
]
```

On the same graph, `WriteGraph` only takes 0.391953 seconds.

Comment: Beat me to it :) I was planning to do the same thing.  I did, however, discover a difference that might explain why Export is slower. Consider g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 3, 4 -> 2, 3 -> 4}];  WriteGraph gives different results from Export.

Comment: In particular, Export flips some of the edges. For example, in the above, WriteGraph gives `e 3 1` whereas Export gives `e 1 3`.  I think that whatever Mathematica is doing here is the reason for the slow down in Export.

Comment: @WalkingRandomly Interesting. I don't see why this is something it should do (AFAIK, the DIMACS format does not specify the order of the endpoints of an edge). Even if `Export` is sorting the edgelist, it shouldn't spend that much time on it (well, this is just my *feeling* :-))

Comment: I don't know enough about the DIMACS format. When I was planning to write my own WriteGraph, I was going to present the answer along with the above observation and ask you if the ordering mattered :)

Comment: @WalkingRandomly BTW, if you (or anyone for that matter) have any suggestions for further speeding up `WriteGraph`, feel free to edit or add a better answer. I'm sure there will be someone else coming after me finding this useful!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and was happy to find this post.

But I needed to include the weights of the edges, as well as the `source s` and the `sink t` The `source` would be the first nodes and the `sink` the last. So, I expanded the formula in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51592/47448, by https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1152/juho to include the weights of the Graph:

```
WriteGraphWeighted[g_, filename_] := 
 Module[{},
  L = EdgeList[g]; 
  weight =  Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g]];
  file = OpenWrite[filename];
  WriteString[file, 
   "c\np max " <> ToString[VertexCount[g]] <> " " <> 
   ToString[EdgeCount[g]] <> "\n"];

   WriteString[file, "n 1 s\n"];
   WriteString[file, "n " <> ToString[VertexCount[g]] <> " t\n"];

  For[i = 1, i <= EdgeCount[g], ++i, 
   first = L[[i]][[1]];
   second = L[[i]][[2]]; 
   third =  weight[[first, second]];
   str = "a " <> ToString[first] <> " " <> ToString[second] <> " " <> 
    ToString[third];
   WriteString[file, str];
   WriteString[file, "\n"];];

  Close[file];
 ]
```

This might be useful for anyone looking at the [DIMACS](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/DIMACS_maxf.htm) format, as used by the [Max-flow problem instances in vision](http://vision.csd.uwo.ca/data/maxflow/) by the Computer Vision Research Group at the University of Western Ontario.